# Will upgrade to 16.04.1 LTS re-enable Network Manager from 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, upgrade

I have a 14.04 distribution that I'm preparing to upgrade to 16.04.1. I have a network configuration that led me to put a stake through the heart of Network Manager (disable it as I loathe it), and I am wondering if a straight upgrade to 16.04.1 will automatically re-enable the beast? I do NOT want this to happen, just to make it clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The install will prompt you when it detects configuration files that has been customized by the user.  It'll prompt you white options that includes retaining your custom version, installing the distribution version, or seeing the difference between the two.  Choose the appropriate one.

An upgrade will retain your configuration.  Some of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries may be disabled.  And some applications that you installed may not be installed after the upgrade.  You can go back and examine the **sources.list** file and reenable the repositories you need.  Then reinstall the applications that didn't carry over.

As far as networkmanager, if you have configured your network by editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, NetworkManager will be disabled for that particular interface.

I believe it's Version 16.04 where the default naming of the network adapter names changed from the `eth0`, `/eth1`,  type to a name similar to  `enp1s0`.  Just look at your network configuration files (which will remain in tack if you choose to keep your version) and replace the old style name to the new style name.

Comment: Thanks LD. I think I've already spotted the /etc/udev files for renaming interfaces, as I'd prefer to keep the traditional device names (and it's what's in some of my other scripts). Appreciate your time and thanks again!